# How to sync data of 2 or more asynchronous requests and send responses with the data parsed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

By taking the simplest example is let's say that they are 2 or more dudes that need to submit data by making an HTTP request, the data submitted by one of the dudes has to wait for the other data to be sent by other dudes to server in order to be parsed. Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish in Node.js:

[image]

When the data is parsed it needs to be sent back as responses to each of the dudes. The problem is that I am stuck on implementing this task(I am using http module, and long polling, later I will use the websocket), the problem resides in the callbacks nature, and I tried using dirty methods like making an array that is filled until everyone submitted and check with the help of setInterval function wherever it's time to parse data and so on.

Is there any cleaner and less messy ways to implement such tasks?

Comment: I'd say that expecting quasi-simultaneous request from two clients *is* a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give a unique id to this process ( which both clients know), then store the related data in a database or directly in the servers RAM. Having pending requests (request - wait) is bad for the server as it has to keep more and more open connections, and bad for the client as he sees a spinning circle without knowing whats happening. I would rather do the following:

```
1. client sends request with data
      2. data gets stored, a *please wait* is returned
3. the page reloads all two seconds
      4. if all the datas there, return the data
      5. if not, return *please wait* and goto 3
```

A pseudoimplementation would look like this:

```
var processes = new Map();

function Process (){
  do {
   var id = Math floor(Math.random()*10**10);
  }while(processes.has(id));
  this.id = id;
  processes.set(id,this);
}

Process.prototype.pending = function(res){
 if(this.first && this.second) 
   return res.end(this.first + this.second);

 res.end(`
  <html>
   <body>
    Please wait... 
    <script> setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location),2000);
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>`);
};

//the routing
var app = Express();

app.get("/create",function(req,res){
 var p = new Process();
 req.end(p.id);
});

app.get("/first/:id/:data",function(req,res){
 var p = processes.get(req.params.id);
 if(!p) return res.end("id not found");
 p.first = req.params.data;
 p.pending(res);
});

app.get("/second/:id/:data",function(req,res){
 var p = processes.get(req.params.id);
 if(!p) return res.end("id not found");
 p.second = req.params.data;
 p.pending(res);
});
```

Comment: so it's like the client make continuous requests for the completed data, in case the server answers a.k.a that searching for other requests is in progress, until finally it receives completed data the next request is with data completed? isn't this a tedious task for the server to receive so many requests(or with the websocket will become less processing hungry task)?

Comment: @domainFlag, yeah the upper code is without websockets and i believe that a 2second poll is less heavy then a pending request. Websockets work similar ( they are not always pending but use polling), however they are more light weight than regular requests, so using websockets may increase the performance. However i havent worked with them for a while, thats why i havent added a ws example...

Comment: your solution works better then everything others provided, and it's better then everything I tried, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the easiest method is to use `Promise.all`

```
function firstAsyncRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do your async call and then resolve();
    // or reject() if any error;
  });
}


function secondAsyncRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do your async call and then resolve();
    // or reject() if any error;
  });
}

Promise.all([firstAsyncRequest, secondAsyncRequest])
  .then(arrayOfResults => {
      //do your logic
  })
  .catch(err => {
      //catch your error
  })
```

If you use callbacks instead the easiest method is to use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module and then `async.parallel`

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

Comment: Can I use Promise.all for more then one processes as mentioned above in async way?

Comment: You may use `Promise.all()` for as many asynchronous requests as you like and once they "all" resolve you will receive their values in an array at the `.then()` stage. However if one of the requests throw an error the whole thing will halt and you will just `.catch()` an error.

Comment: Dunno but the promise and async solution doesn't work, because you can't provide the other callbacks when you don't know when the client request will be intercepted by the server and it's a mess of scopes, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As i have mentioned in my comment `promise.all()` is fine but you don't have any control on resolving promises once one of them gets rejected.

Instead you may sequence your promises with a `.reduce()` and you will have much more control both on resolved and rejected promises.

```js
var pr1 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.2 ? v("promise 1 resolved value") : x("Promise 1 rejected"),150)),
    pr2 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.2 ? v("promise 2 resolved value") : x("Promise 2 rejected"),120)),
    pr3 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.2 ? v("promise 3 resolved value") : x("Promise 3 rejected"),60)),
    pr4 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.2 ? v("promise 4 resolved value") : x("Promise 4 rejected"),220)),
    pr5 = new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.2 ? v("promise 5 resolved value") : x("Promise 5 rejected"),180));

[pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5].reduce((p,c) => p.then(v => (console.log(`doing something with ${v} and will proceed with the next`),c),
                                             x => (console.log(`Error ${x} however i will proceed with the next`),c)))
                     .then(v => console.log(`finally doing something with ${v}`),
                           x => console.log(`Error ${x} received`));
```