# Why does Promise.all().then() still make the output synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am working on an exercise on Javascript and the point is to make everything work in an asynchronous way. The exercise goes like this: To have an array that is to be filled with random numbers. Then the max element of this array will be the length of a rectangular 2D-Array. For every unique element in the array that is to be used as an index in the 2D-array, i must find the sum of the rows and columns in the 2D-array, as well as the sum of the surrounding elements in the 2D-array. These tasks need to be done separately, and i used Promises. But when i log on the console to see how the work is taking place, it still outputs it synchronously, or even worse it starts searching on the arrays even before they are filled. I am new to this, so i need some guidance.

```
var arrayA = [];
var matricaA = [];
var n=10;
var m;
var arr = [];
var k = 0;
var funcMatrixHolder = [];
var result = [];

function genRandomNum(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function fillArray(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    arrayA = Array.from({length: n}, () => genRandomNum(1,10));
    m = arrayA[0];
    arrayA.filter(function(pos){
      if(pos > m) {
        m = pos;
      }
      resolve(m);
    });
  });
}

function createMatrix(size) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    arr = Array.from({length: size}, () => genRandomNum(1,10));
    //console.log(arr);
    resolve(arr);
  });
}

function sumRowCol(matrix, len, arr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var shuma=0;
      arr.filter(function(elem, pos) {
      var poz = elem-1;
        if(arr.indexOf(elem) === pos) { //per cdo element unik
          for(var k = 0; k<len; k++){
            sum+=matrix[k][poz];
            sum+=matrix[poz][k];
            //console.log(k);
            //
            }
          }
          resolve(sum);
          console.log(sum+" sum"); //to check how it works
          sum=0;
      })
  });
}

function sumNr(myArray, arr) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var sum = 0;
      arr.filter(function(elem, pos) {
      var rowLimit = myArray.length-1;
      var columnLimit = myArray[0].length-1;
      var i = elem-1;
      var j = elem-1
      if(arr.indexOf(elem) === pos) { //per cdo element unik
            for(var x = Math.max(0, i-1); x <= Math.min(i+1, rowLimit); x++) {
              for(var y = Math.max(0, j-1); y <= Math.min(j+1, columnLimit); y++) {
                if(x !== i || y !== j) {
                  sum += myArray[x][y];
                  //
                }
              }
            }
            console.log(sum + "sum");
            resolve(sum);
            sum = 0;
          }

        })
  })
}

fillArray(n).then(function(result) {
  //filled array and got it's max
});

while(k<m) {
  funcMatrixHolder.push(createMatrix(m));
  k++;
}

//console.log(funcMatrixHolder);

Promise.all(funcMatrixHolder).then(function(result) {
  matricaA = result;
});


Promise.all([sumNr(matricaA,arrayA),sumRowCol(matricaA,m,arrayA)]).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` wont sequence the promises it will just run them in parallel. You may consider chaining them up with a `.reduce()`

Comment: @Redu i will read what `.reduce()` is all about. Thanks

Comment: Given there is nothing inherently asynchronous in your code, you should not be using promises at all?!

Comment: You may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45904958/4543207) answer for an idea. It's not exactly doing the same thing but will give an idea on how you may chain them up with `.reduce()`

Comment: @Bergi Probably i may have the concept wrong. But i was asked to do it async with promises. But as i said, i am new to this and maybe i have all of it wrong.

Comment: Like @Bergi said you benefit nothing from promises here.  But if you did have any async functions, like ajax etc..  Another neat option in modern javascript is the `async / await`..

Comment: You're having three separate promise chains - `fillArray(n).then(…)`, `Promise.all(funcMatrixHolder).then(…)` and `Promise.all([…]).then(…)`. They are independent and will run concurrently, there's nothing that would make them wait for each other. Especially the last call won't wait for the `matricaA = result;` assignment in the asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi I understand. But since the chains are dependent from the variables, it gives me an error because it starts iterating through the array while it is still not full.

Comment: @minus.273 You might ask your instructor again what exactly should happen asynchronously in the process. Promises don't make synchronous code better or more performant.

Comment: @minus.273 Yes. Just put the things that need to wait inside the callback then.

Comment: @Bergi I see. As you and Keith up there said, i can understand now that there is no async function in my code. Maybe my instructor just meant to make the functions work in parallel. I will ask. And thank you for the tips

Comment: Although promises are meant to be used with asynchronous code, in seldom cases you may utilize them to retard some cpu intensive synchronous jobs (by inserting them at a microtask queue) in a similar fashion to what `setTimeout` would do. So `new Promise(function(v,x){var i = 0; while (i <100) i++; v(i); }).then(v => console.log(v)); console.log("here");` will print `here` before`100`. I believe microtasks are handled before event queues so it's a kind of compromise when needed. For a good read  on this particular topic https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: @Redu Except that the microtask queue still blocks macrotasks, so promises alone aren't useful here. You still need `setTimeout(…, 0)` - although wrapping *that* in a promise will of course simplify code. (Also in your example, the intensive `v(i)` loop still runs before `console.log("here")`, as the `Promise` constructor is synchronous)

Comment: @Bergi Yes thanks for reminding. I should instead do like `Promise.resolve(intensiveFunc).then(f => f(arg)).then(v => console.log(v)); console.log("i am processed first");`. Yes for sure this would block the microtask queue so would the event loop queue if put async by `setTimeout`. I wonder if CPU intensive jobs at the microtask que block the event loop too? I guess anything available in the microtask queue magically gets inserted to the front of the event loop. Is this so..?

Comment: @Redu Yes, the microtask queue blocks the macrotask queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, this is the answer that got approved as correct:
(Excuse the non-english labels)

```
var arrayA = [];
var matricaA = [];
var n=10;
var m;
var arr = [];
var k = 0;
var funcMatrixHolder = [];
var result_final = [];
var filterArr = [];
var result_final_final = [];

function genRandomNum(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function fillArray(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

    arrayA = Array.from({length: n}, () => genRandomNum(1,10));
    m = arrayA[0];
    arrayA.filter(function(elem, pos){
      if(elem > m) {
        m = elem;
      }
      if(arrayA.indexOf(elem) === pos) {
        filterArr.push(elem);
      }
    });
    var fArrPH = {
      max: m,
      fArr: filterArr
    }
    resolve(fArrPH);
  });
}

function createMatrix(size) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    arr = Array.from({length: size}, () => genRandomNum(1,10));
    //console.log(arr);
    resolve(arr);

  });
}

function fillArrayFunction(size) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    for (var i=0; i<size; i++){
      funcMatrixHolder.push(createMatrix(size));
    }
    resolve(funcMatrixHolder);
  })
}



function shumaRreshtKolone(matrix, index, madhesia) {
          let shuma=0;
          //console.log(madhesia);
          for(var k = 0; k<madhesia; k++){
            //console.log(index);
            //index = 10;
            shuma+=matrix[k][index];
            shuma+=matrix[index][k];

            }
           console.log("ShumaRreshtKolone u llogarit.");
          return shuma;
}

function sumNrRrethues(myArray, index) {
     var sum = 0;
      var rowLimit = myArray.length-1;
      var columnLimit = myArray[0].length-1;
      var i = index-1;
      var j = index-1
            for(var x = Math.max(0, i-1); x <= Math.min(i+1, rowLimit); x++) {
              for(var y = Math.max(0, j-1); y <= Math.min(j+1, columnLimit); y++) {
                if(x !== i || y !== j) {
                  sum += myArray[x][y];
                }
              }
            }
            console.log("ShumaNrRrethues u llogarit");
            return sum;
}

var m1;
function job() {
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    fillArray(n).then(function(result) {
       //console.log("array", result);
        m1 = result;
        return fillArrayFunction(result.max);
    }).then(function(result) {
      Promise.all(result).then(function(result) {
        matricaA = result;
        console.log(matricaA);
        console.log(arrayA);
        m1.fArr.map(function(item) {
           //console.log("item", item);
          return result_final.push({
            Elementi: m1.fArr.indexOf(item),
            ShumaRreshtKolone: shumaRreshtKolone(matricaA,item-1,m1.max),
            ShumaNrRrethues: sumNrRrethues(matricaA, item-1)
          });
        });
        resolve(result_final);
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
  })
}

job().then(function(result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```